# MongoDB: InMatchExpression equality cannot be undefined

Tags: mongodb

I have the following query:

```js
db.Artworks.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Artists",
      localField : "Artist",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "Artist"
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$Artist" },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      "Artist.DisplayName":1
    }
  }
])
```

which works as I'd expect giving the output:

```json
{ "Artist" : { "DisplayName" : "Otto Wagner" } }
{ "Artist" : { "DisplayName" : "Christian de Portzamparc" } }
{ "Artist" : { "DisplayName" : "Bernard Tschumi" } }
{ "Artist" : { "DisplayName" : "Emil Hoppe" } }
{ "Artist" : { "DisplayName" : "Bernard Tschumi" } }
{ "Artist" : { "DisplayName" : "Bernard Tschumi" } }
{ "Artist" : { "DisplayName" : "Bernard Tschumi" } }
{ "Artist" : { "DisplayName" : "Bernard Tschumi" } }
{ "Artist" : { "DisplayName" : "Emil Hoppe" } }
```

However then when I attempt to do a match on this query like so:

```js
db.Artworks.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Artists",
      localField : "Artist",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "Artist"
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$Artist" },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      "Artist.DisplayName":1
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "Artist.DisplayName": "Otto Wagner"
    }
  }
])
```

I get the following error:

> Error: command failed: {
> "ok" : 0,
> "errmsg" : "InMatchExpression equality cannot be undefined",
> "code" : 2,
> "codeName" : "BadValue"
> } : aggregate failed at src/mongo/shell/assert.js:13

Why is this? How can I do a `$match` without getting this error?

Comment: I also encountered this error, in my case when using `$lookup` specifically where my `localField` was an array which `undefined` as one of its elements. I'm assuming that in your case it might occur because one of your documents' `Artist` field is `undefined`. Try to either set `Artist` to any value other than `undefined` (such as `null`) or delete the document completely.